# Разделить строку

Tags: php

Такой вопрос - передаю данные ajax'ом в обработчик. Получаю 2 id вот так

```
     if (!empty($_POST['prod_id'])) {
            $prod_id = $_POST['prod_id'];

            echo 'ID: '.implode(', ', $prod_id).'<br />';
```

получаю следующее: ID: 1, 2

Как можно разделить полученные данные на 2 переменные, например: $prod_1 и $prod_2 ?

Answer (score 1):

А может лучше всё-таки работать с массивом?

Вы уверены что ID всегда будет только два?

Comment: Да, только 2

Comment: Можете объяснить на моем примере как сделать с массивом ?

Comment: Код в ответе был неправильный. Что-то я тупанул.

Если `$_POST['prod_id']` это строка состоящая из значений с разделителями (например замятыми) то получить из неё массив можно функцией `explode()` которая делает из строки массив используя переданный ей разделитель.
    $prod_id = explode(',', $prod_id);
    echo $prod_id[0]; echo $prod_id[1];

Но если это строка то непонятно зачем в приведённом вами коде используется implode (который делает строку из массива).

Comment: Советую почитать:

http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php 
http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php 
http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.list.php

Comment: Если ID может быть только два то лучше действительно использовать list()

Answer (score 1):

Код, который вы приводите в вопросе подразумевает, что ajax'ом приходит не строка, а массив. Поэтому как-то так можно:

```
if (!empty($_POST['prod_id'])) {
    $prod_id = $_POST['prod_id']; // ожидается, что $prod_id это массив, но может быть и строкой/числом
    if( is_array( $prod_id) && count( $prod_id) == 2) { 
        // массив, и ровно два элемента!
        $prod_1 = $prod_id[0];
        $prod_2 = $prod_id[1];
    } else {
        // Паника! Это не массив, или пришло не два элемента. Пора на море.
    }
} else {
    // Не прислали нам никаких prod_id в этот раз : (
}
```

Comment: Дело. Я одного не пойму, почему `$_POST['prod_id']` это уже из коробки массив? Или клиент посылает два `prod_id` как два независимых элемента `POST` запроса, а php склеивает одноимённые элементы в массив?

P.S. не лучше-ли использовать конструкцию list() для присвоения значений переменным?

Comment: Видимо, `ajax` присылает эти данные как массив, раз в примере автора вопроса работает `implode()`.

В общем варианте `list()` не лучше, так как выкинет ошибку, если `$prod_id` окажется не массивом, или в нем будет менее двух элементов. В моем коде, после проверок — вполне можно использовать и конструкцию `list()`.

Answer (score -1):

Если вы уверены, что там маcсив из двух элементов, то так:

```
list($prod_1,$prod_2) = $prod_id;
```

Но лучше все же проверить, что это массив, и что элементов два)